# Nginx folder redirection without changing the url

Tags: redirect, nginx

I want to redirect an old path to a new one without changing the url and keeping the suffix of the url for the redirection:

> dev-osm.blah.com/NYC/v2/site/links?key=a12345

redirect to

> dev-osm.blah.com/NYC/v1/site/links2?key=a12345

```
server {
   server_name  dev-osm.blah.com
.
.

location ^~ /NYC/v2/site/links {
   rewrite ^ /NYC/v1/site/links2
}
```

Comment: While nginx' configuration format is super complex as configuration formats go and includes a number of features that programming languages do, it's not really a programming language, making this question a little off-topic for StackOverflow. You might have better luck over at http://ServerFault.com/.

Answer (score -1):

Use something like the following in your server config

```
location /NYC/v2
proxy_pass: /NYC/v1/
```